# joining two tables while one column has multiple values

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

table 1 - employee

```
id  empname
--------------
1   Andy
2   Brady
3   Khalid
```

table 2 - clients

```
id name empid
----------------
1  client1   1,2
2  client2   3,2
3  client3   3
```

I want to get that Andy and Brady serve the client 1 and Brady and Khalid server client2 and Khalid server client3. How can I do this?

Comment: You tagged mysql AND oracle. Are you using 2 different databases at the same time ?

Comment: You should not be storing data as delimited lists (instead use a bridging table to connect the two tables). If you must use a delimited list (don't) then you can join using `',' || clients.empid || ',' LIKE '%,' || employee.id || ',%'` to match between the two tables (as per the linked duplicate). You should not need to split the column into rows.

Comment: If you are using MySQL you can use `FIND_IN_SET(employee.id, clients.empid)`, but you should normalize this relationship to a junction (many-to-many) table, which can be indexed effectively and is more scalable.